Convert attribute table to CSV using arcpy
How do I convert the attribute table of a layer in an ArcGIS Pro project to a CSV using ArcPy?
I need it as a CSV so I can work on the data in the layer in pandas. I'm working in ArcGIS Pro.
I know I can do this manually but I want to do it using ArcPy so I can automate the process. I just need to grab the layer and export it as a csv.

What have you tried?  Please [edit] your question to include a snippet of the code you've tried, and details of what happens when you try it.  In what way is it working or not working?

Why not read the attribute table direct to pandas?

I have not tried anything, because I havent found anything. Im simply asking if there is some module or class of a module in arcpy that deals with exporting data as csv. I know how to export data as a csv without code but i need assistance with exporting the data of a feature class as a csv with code in arcpy.

I didn't know you could read the attribute table directly in pandas.

You could make a table view of the attribute table.  Then export the table view to CSV.
